# Appending data to a Python array is giving an error

Tags: python, arrays

I am practicing with beautifulsoup, and I am trying to have the code isolate the links found in the page, and then retrieve them. My "print (link.get("href"))" line prints the whole list of links, so that part works. What I am struggling with is being able to now save the list into an array so that I can play with the data. In this example, Iam trying to print the 5th element in the list.

The error I get is "IndexError: list assignment index out of range"

Below is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

i=0
array1 = []
r = requests.get("http://www.yellowpages.ca/bus/Quebec/Rimouski/Walmart/8139565.html")
var = r.content

soup= BeautifulSoup(var)

soup.find_all("a")
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    print (link.get("href"))
    array1[i+1] = link.get("href")

print (array1(5))
```

Thanks.

Using Python 3.4, and bs4

Comment: You're getting the error because the second element in the array doesn't exist and you're trying to add it in the incorrect way. Change `array1[i+1] = link.get("href")` to `array1.append(link.get("href"))` and you should be fine.

Comment: thanks brittenb, this worked!!

Comment: can you post it as an answer, so i can label the question answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is because the second element in the array doesn't exist. So when you try to index the array by assigning to the second element (remember, Python indexing starts at 0), Python is telling you that element doesn't exist and it stops. To fix this, we have to append our data in the proper way. We can do this simply by changing `array1[i+1] = link.get("href")` to `array1.append(link.get("href"))`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a list comprehension:

`array1 = [link.get('href') for link in soup.find_all('a')]`